# Animate multiple properties in an object simultaniously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know, that it is possible to animate (nearly) any object in jQuery using the `.animate()`-function, however I have this small problem:

My jQuery somehow refuses to animate multiple properties of an object at once.

This is my code:

```
$({
    s: prg,
    r: rem,
    t: tot
}).animate({
    s: prg + trans / 1000,
    r: rem + trans / 1000,
    t: tot + trans / 1000
}, {
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: trans,
    step: function(now) {
        $('#val_p').text(now.s);
        $('#val_r').text(now.r);
        $('#val_t').text(now.t);
    }
});
```

When hovering on the `now`-variable during debugging, I see that it is the value of the property `s`.

My question is: How do I animate all three properties at once (in parallel)?

---

**EDIT: №1:** [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575658/animate-multiple-properties-in-an-object-simultaniously?noredirect=1#comment58838221_35575658) written by the User [Frédéric Hamidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464709/fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-hamidi) helped me by pointing to the official [`.animate()`-documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step).

*The thread is hereby closed.*

Comment: `step` is called once per animated property. Apparently you're only debugging the first call (the `s` property) on every iteration. You should get two other calls (one for `r` and one for `t`) by iteration.

Comment: What kind of elements are $('#val_p') etc? Because the .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val() method.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: How do I debug the other calls -- _and more importantly:_ How do I know which property I am currently accessing? Should I use that using modulo 3?

Comment: @TobiasBeuving: They are `div`s - but this is not relevant here, as the current code does not work with `$('title').text(......)` or any other accessor.

Comment: @Unknown, `step` actually takes two arguments, `now` and `fx` (see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step)). `fx.prop` contains the name of the property currently being animated.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: right you are, Sir - I somehow must have overseen that